# Update plugin parameter for Dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

Using Dygraphs I can setup a plugin on initial load

```
plugins: [
    new Dygraph.Plugins.Crosshair({
    direction: "both"
    })
]
```

But I don't seem to be able to change the direction parameter with `updateOptions`

I tried

```
var pluginOpt = {};

pluginOpt = { 

    plugins: [
        new Dygraph.Plugins.Crosshair({
        direction: "neither"
        })
    ]

 };

 g.updateOptions({
      plugins: pluginOpt
 });
```

Also tried just passing `direction` , both fail silently, with nothing updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change plugins using `updateOptions`. Sorry. If the plugin wants to support updates, it needs to provide an API for doing it. This could definitely be better.

In the meantime, your workaround is to destroy the dygraph and create a new one with the plugin settings you like.

Comment: Indeed, I suppose I need to add some `setDirection` method or something to `Dygraph.Plugins.Crosshair` plugin: https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/821

Answer (score 0):

You need  to install dygraphs and types/dygraphs
`npm i dygraphs --save
npm i @types/dygraphs --save`

Then you need to insert these lines to work with plugins:

`require('./../../../../node_modules/dygraphs/src/extras/synchronizer.js');`
`declare var Dygraph:any;`

Change the path in the require string according to your project and you can use the plugin while creating the graph. Sample code from my project which is working:

`this.graph = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"), 
        this.data,
        {
          legend: 'always',
          drawPoints: true,
          animatedZooms: true,
          showRoller: true,
          plugins: [
            new Dygraph['Plugins'].Crosshair({
              direction: "vertical"
            }),
          ]
        })`

I got it working in Angular 8.